# Newbie PyCharm Question about Debugging Function Calls

Tags: pycharm, ide

usually when I do `ctrl + <left click>` on a method name it'll take me to it's definition. If I have multiple implementations of that function with different arguments it will ask me to select a declaration. At run-time how can I tell which method declaration will be executed?

So far I've tried going into debug mode and viewing it that way to no avail. I know I could put breakpoints in each implementation to see which instances are run, but it seems like there's a better way to accomplish this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Step Into` action (Run - Debugging Actions - Step Into or F7), it will navigate you into the actual implementation.

Some debugging actions are described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stepping-through-the-program.html.